# color change delay with bootstrap collapse row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change the color of collapsed rows inside my table but for some reason there is a delay. When you hit the icon the rows expand but there is a delay before the colors change. Is there a way around this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dy83cxaw/1/)

```
.table>tbody>tr.collapse>td {
background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap removes the `collapsed` class during the transition when the elements are shown, and only adds it again after that transition has ended.

However, it adds the class `collapsing` during that transition – so if you give elements that have that class the red background color as well, it should work as you want it to.

```
.table>tbody>tr.collapse>td,
.table>tbody>tr.collapsing>td{
    background-color:red;
}

.table>tbody>tr:not(.collapse):not(.collapsing):nth-child(odd)>td {
    background-color:#ecf3f8;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dy83cxaw/5/

Comment: FYI: The `nth-child(odd)` selector takes the rows that are currently not shown into account as well – so if you want to show only the rows that _are_ visible in alternating colors, that won’t work here.

Comment: Thanks! And Thanks for the FYI too, that also helps with the striping issue I have as well.